# Is "In der Pfeife rauchen" an idiom?

Tags: meaning, idiom

I have seen this phrase a couple times now and I'm not sure what it means. It was in the headline of an article on [Der Spiegel online](http://www.spiegel.de/sport/fussball/frauenfussball-wm-2015-viel-aerger-ueber-den-kunstrasen-a-1008107.html):

> Frauenfußball-WM: Das Gras? Kannst du in der Pfeife rauchen

Google translate wasn't much help in this area.
Is it an idiom? And what does it mean?

Comment: The "können" is a part of the idiom: "den/die/das kannst du in der Pfeife rauchen"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It basically means: "You can forget it, it is crap". Here, it is even funnier, as "Gras" is a german slang word for marijuana.

Comment: Was soll "Gras in der Pfeife rauchen" im Kontext Frauenfussball+Marihuana bedeuten? Eine falsche Fährte, hier. Gras in der Pfeife rauchen macht ja Spaß und dieses Gras ist besonders teuer - hat also die gegenteilige Bedeutung. Das macht keinen Sinn.

Comment: And once in the past, "marijuana" was a slang word for cannabis, rooting in mexican parlance, introduced by companies campaigning against weed (because they prospected pot as dangerous to their business).

Answer (score 0):

Marijuana often is smoked in a pipe, Pfeife in German. *Gras* is another word for marijuana in German, often used in the slang. In this headline, *Gras* stands for the grass used in the women's world cup. Because it was that bad, you can't use it for playing football on it, you can just *smoke it in a pipe* (in der Pfeife rauchen).

Comment: Besonders schlechtes Gras will niemand in Pfeifen rauchen.